# Path to image from database in React.js

Tags: reactjs, json, image, path, src

I dont know how to correct load path to img in react. When I do it this way everything works fine.

```
<img src = {require('../Images/komputer5.jpg')} alt = "productImage"></img>
```

But when I try to load this path from JSON i have error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../Images/komputer5.jpg'
```

Path in JSON

```
"image": "../Images/komputer5.jpg"
```

I tried to do it this way, but it didnt work

```
<img src = {require(product.image)} alt = "productImage"></img>
```

Can someone told me how do I get it to work in?

Comment: Can you explain about your directory architecture that you are using right now?

Comment: Src -> Images || 

src -> components -> products (from here I want to upload a photo)

Answer (score 2):

change the json like this

```
"image": "komputer5.jpg"
```

then add the relative path

```
 require(`../Images/${product.image}`)
```